# ng-click no funciona con ng-view

Tags: angularjs, views

he empezado a crear una pagina. tiene cabecera y main, el main carga las vistas y funciona perfectamente, pero quiero que cuando se carguen las vistas secundarias se esconda la cabecera, aquí el index:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sistemas.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desarrollo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/personal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/profesional.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sistemas.js"></script>
    <script src="animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" >
    <main ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="ver=true">
        <section class="cabecera" ng-show="ver==true">
            <article>
                <!-- Aquí va la cabecera -->
            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="cuerpo" ng-view ng-click="ver=showTitle();">

        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

y aquí el js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
    })
    .when('/sistemas', {
        templateUrl: 'views/sistemas.html'
    })
    .when('/desarrollo', {
        templateUrl: 'views/desarrollo.html'
    })
    .when('/profesional', {
        templateUrl: 'views/profesional.html'
    })
    .when('/personal', {
        templateUrl: 'views/personal.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
$scope.showTitle = function() {
var ver = $scope.ver;
    if (ver == true) {
        ver=false;
    } 
    else {
        ver=true;
    }
return ver;
}
});
```

Si lo pongo en cualquier otra section funciona perfectamente, pero parece que el ng-view interfiere con el funcionamiento del ng-click, ¿a alguien más le ha pasado?

*editado: disculpad por haberlo puesto en inglés al principio, casi todos los posts que he visto de AngularJS(Angular 1) estaban en inglés.

Comment: Jorge, esta comunidad es hispanohablante, te pido que traduzcas tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, un amigo me ayudó con esto, es un problema de ámbito, hay que declarar la variable en $rootscope, desde app.run